# Phalcon save zip file to server using Incubator HTTP Client

Tags: php, curl, download, phalcon

With the [Phalcon Incubator library's HTTP client](https://github.com/phalcon/incubator/tree/master/Library/Phalcon/Http/Client) you are able to make web requests. 
I would like to download a zip file from another server to a specific folder in my Phalcon project.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$provider = Request::getProvider();
$provider->header->set('Accept', 'application/zip');
$provider->get('https://phs.googlecode.com/files/Download%20File%20Test.zip');
```

How do I save this zip to a specific location after the request is made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$provider = Request::getProvider();
$provider->header->set('Accept', 'application/zip');
$response = $provider->get('https://phs.googlecode.com/files/Download%20File%20Test.zip');

file_put_contents('/path/to/file.zip', $response->body);
```

Comment: Where does `/` start? The root of your Phalcon project?

Comment: [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/file_put_contents) needs the full path to the file (as would fopen) so it starts from the root of the server.